# Magento 2.2.7 Warning - The directory cannot be deleted: rmdir() Text file busy

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.7

I am getting the following error while running the  bin/magento setup:di:compile command using a linux VM(Laravel Homestead) in a windows host.

```
The directory "/var/www/projectname/generated/code/Composer/Console" cannot be deleted 
Warning! rmdir(/var/www/projectname/generated/code/Composer/Console): Text file busy
```

How do I fix it? I have tried changing the syslink option to copy in the di.xml (app/etc/di.xml) but the error is still there.

I am also getting a similar error while changing to the developer mode

```
The directory "/var/www/projectname/var/cache/mage--0" cannot be deleted 
Warning! rmdir(/var/www/projectname/var/cache/mage--0): Text file busy
```

Comment: Hi Sreejith,

Did you resolve this issue, I am getting the same issue on host windows 10 and running ubuntu as guest os. I am running command setup:di:compile and getting same error "Text file busy". I think it's related to shared folder. If you have resolved it please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: This problem happen when I was using Homestead on windows 10. It has something to do with the file permission of the auto generated code. I tried different methods, but none of it was successful so I moved the magento installation to a non shared folder in Homestead.

Answer (score 0):

I am having almost the same problem with host: Windows 7 and Guest: Ubuntu 19.10. Wordpress works OK but Magento has no CSS or Javascript and I can't decompile or deploy static content, I just get a load of errors like:

```
The Directory "/var/www/html/generated/..." cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(var/www/html/generated/...): Text file busy
```

The closest guess I can make is that Windows is not allowing permissions on the files despite me giving them.